# Uniswap V2 getsAmountIn > getsAmountOut on the same pair

Tags: python, ethereum

I do not get why the result of getAmountsIn is always higher than getAmountsOut on the same pair.
The same thing happens on both Uniswap and Sushiswap.

I'm using python with the following code

```
from helper import *
from decimal import Decimal

wethAddr = '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2'
usdcAddr = '0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7'

amount = uniRouter.functions.getAmountsOut(web3.to_wei(Decimal('1'), 'ether'), [wethAddr, usdcAddr]).call()
amount2 = sushiRouter.functions.getAmountsOut(web3.to_wei(Decimal('1'), 'ether'), [wethAddr, usdcAddr]).call()
amount3 = uniRouter.functions.getAmountsIn(web3.to_wei(Decimal('1'), 'ether'), [usdcAddr, wethAddr]).call()
amount4 = sushiRouter.functions.getAmountsIn(web3.to_wei(Decimal('1'), 'ether'), [usdcAddr, wethAddr]).call()

print(amount[1])
print(amount2[1])
print(amount3[0])
print(amount4[0])
```

Is anyone able to explain me why the getAmountsIn value is Always higher than the getAmountsOut value?

Comment: I guess itt depends if the fees are taken on the input or output: are you giving it fees-inclusive or fees-exclusive way to calculate prices.

Comment: Where does the `helper` module come from, and what does it define?